# Assigning or changing int property using enum inside QML

Tags: qt, enums, qml, qtquick2

Consider this simple enum class:

```
#include <QObject>
class BookTypes : public QObject
{
    Q_GADGET
    Q_ENUMS(AllBooksType)    

public:

    enum AllBooksType{
        eMagazine,
        eReference,
        eTextBook,
        eThesis
    };

signals:

public slots:

};
```

Type registration in `main()`

```
qmlRegisterUncreatableType<BookTypes>("trial", 1, 0, "BookTypes", 
"Don't create qml instance for BookTypes");
```

And this is sample QML:

```
Rectangle {
        id: rect
        x: 100; y: 100
        width: 100
        height: 70
        color: "PowderBlue"
        border.color: "RoyalBlue"
        border.width: 1
        radius: 3

        MouseArea{
            x: 0; y: 0
            height: parent.height
            width: parent.width
            property int bt: BookTypes.eTextBook //perfect. now bt is 2
            onClicked: {
                console.debug("old book type:- ")
                console.debug(bt) //prints 2
                console.debug("selected book type:- ")
                bt = BookTypes.eReference //gives error - why ?
                console.debug(BookTypes.eReference) //prints 'undefined'
                console.debug(bt)
            }
        }
    }
```

This means that the enum is properly exposed, since it initializes `bt` successfully in

```
property int bt: BookTypes.eTextBook
```

What I don't understand is: why it is not accessible when I try to replace value of `bt` in handler:

```
bt = BookTypes.eReference //gives error - why ?
```

How do I pass such an `enum` as an argument of `Q_INVOKABLE` method, for instance:

```
console.debug(BookTypes.eReference) //prints 'undefined'
SomeObj.someCPPMethod(BookTypes.eReference) // sends 'undefined' and defaults to 0
```

Comment: By the way, Q_GADGET is "a lighter version of the Q_OBJECT macro for classes that do not inherit from QObject but still want to use some of the reflection capabilities offered by QMetaObject." I'm not sure if deriving from QObject is a good idea; you should probably do one or the other.

Comment: yes @Mitch Thanks! 
This snippet is one of the trial and error portion. In actual code i will be using QObjects throughout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#enumeration-types):

> Note: The names of enum values must begin with a capital letter in order to be accessible from QML.

Which does beg the question: Why does it work in the property binding?  I've no idea, probably a Qt bug.

Comment: Good Lord ! 
Thanks a lot !! this is a life saver.. @cmannett85